# Best practices to save password on a vuejs projects?

Tags: javascript, security, vue.js

I need to display a user profile view. A user can update their profile and password?

In my first idea, I can save a password in the storageSession encrypt it's more secure but I don't know it's a good best practices.
In the project, we use vuex and storageSession, not cookies.

Comment: The best practice is probably to don't store the password at all in the client. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: i need to store the password because, the front end send a user object with password for the backend.   But if i use the REST API  getUser(id),  it doesn't return the password.
so i need to store this in the client if the user need to change the password.

Comment: It's very unlikely that you need to store the password to change it.

Comment: Did you already find a solution for this issue? I have similar case.